# UITableView will not scroll or select

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I don't understand. My application suddenly stopped letting any uitableviews scroll or be selected. I can set tables to edit mode and delete cells, but for some crazy reason it's like I can't interact with tableviews. Of course the delegate, datasource, delegate methods, and everything are hooked up. I even did the same thing in another project and it worked perfectly.

Does anyone know any reason that a table view would stop responding?

Comment: Hi, you should check if the userInteractionEnabled of your  uitableview  is YES. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Try reloading (what is even better is reload with a tiny delay, say 0.5 second) your tableview at some point of your view controller's life cycle. It happens, I mean the *tableview freezing* thing, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 2 things are checked:

```
[tableview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[tableView setScrollable:yes];
```

Place a breakpoint in the cell for row at index path see whats happening.

Are the cells displaying anything. Evreything in IB hooked up including datasource and delegate?

Comment: yeah I have already tried those things. I created a workaround, but I'm not sure why it works. My view was originally in a cameraoverlayview, so I simply removed the imagepicker view and added the separate view with my table and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IB, make sure your `UITableView` has **User Interaction Enable** selected?

Comment: Yeah I've definitely done this. I can interact with the tableview when it's in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't happen to remove or override any swipe and scroll gesture from your UITableView did you?